# SAMBA(Openwrt) Share not show in File explorer (Windows 7)

Tags: linux, windows, configuration, samba, samba4

I have this configuration with Samba 4.14.12:

```
[global]
        netbios name = MyRouter
        interfaces = br-lan eth0 
        server string = MyRouter
        unix charset = UTF-8
        workgroup = WORKGROUP

        bind interfaces only = yes

        #server min protocol = SMB2
        passdb backend = smbpasswd
        dns proxy = no
        socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY
        use sendfile = yes
        map to guest = Bad User
        load printers = no
        printcap name = /dev/null
        disable spoolss = yes
        printing = bsd
        client signing = mandatory

        ## disable core dumps
        enable core files = no
        #smb encrypt = desired
        security = user
        mdns name = mdns


        #delete veto files = yes

######### Dynamic written config options #########
        disable netbios = yes
        smb ports = 445
        aio read size = 0
        aio write size = 0

[HDDSoft]
        path = /media/HDDSoft/HDD_DATI/+PC
        create mask = 0666
        directory mask = 0777
        read only = yes
        guest ok = no
        guest only = yes

[hdd]
        path = /media/HDDSoft/HDD_DATI
        valid users = root
        create mask = 0666
        directory mask = 0777
        browseable = no
        read only = no
        guest ok = no
```

Why doesn't it show in network File Explorer?

Comment: eth0 is "wan". The interfaces are all set up correctly

Comment: The version is **4.14.12**

Comment: On your Windows7 client, can you successfully get to `\\MyRouter`?

Comment: Yes. If I try to do "direct access" it works ...

Comment: Does your W7 client see other devices in your network? If not, have you activated network discovery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I solved the problem***. The problem is that the **wsdd** (WSD/LLMNR Discovery/Name Service Daemon) protocol was missing.

From package **wsdd2** on [Github](https://github.com/Netgear/wsdd2)

> With Microsoft turning off SMB1 feature completely on Windows 10, any
> Samba shares on the local network become invisible to Windows
> computers (**start from windows 7**). That's due to the fact that SMB1 is required for Computer
> Browser service to function. **Newer Windows systems can use WSD (Web Services for Devices) to discover shares hosted on other computers**
>
> The primary purpose of this project is to enable WSD on Samba servers
> so that network shares hosted on a Unix box can appear in Windows File
> Explorer / Network.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 uses SMB version 2.1. Recent versions of Samba prefer version 3. Uncomment this instruction to ensure backwards compatibility:

```
server min protocol = SMB2
```

Also (as suggested in my [earlier comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/720354/sambaopenwrt-share-not-show-in-file-explorer-windows-7#comment1366140_720354)) does your W7 client see other devices in your network? If not, make sure you have activated network discovery as it's not always on by default.

Comment: Done. But it doesn't work anyway