# SAMBA Share (with no user) windows 7 ask user/password

Tags: linux, windows, configuration, samba, shared-folders

I have a samba folder share without user/auth (access via guest):

This is config (OpenWrt):

```
[global]
    #netbios name = |NAME| 
    netbios name = HDDSoft
    interfaces = |INTERFACES|
    server string = |DESCRIPTION|
    unix charset = |CHARSET|
    workgroup = |WORKGROUP|

    ## This global parameter allows the Samba admin to limit what interfaces on a machine will serve SMB requests.
    bind interfaces only = yes

    ## time for inactive connections to-be closed in minutes
    deadtime = 15

    ## disable core dumps
    enable core files = no

    ## set security (auto, user, domain, ads)
    security = user

    ## This parameter controls whether a remote client is allowed or required to use SMB encryption.
    ## It has different effects depending on whether the connection uses SMB1 or SMB2 and newer:
    ## If the connection uses SMB1, then this option controls the use of a Samba-specific extension to the SMB protocol introduced in Samba 3.2 that makes use of the Unix extensions.
    ## If the connection uses SMB2 or newer, then this option controls the use of the SMB-level encryption that is supported in SMB version 3.0 and above and available in Windows 8 and newer. 
    ## (default/auto,desired,required,off)
    #smb encrypt = default

    ## set invalid users
        invalid users = root
    
        ## map unknow users to guest
    map to guest = Bad User

    ## allow client access to accounts that have null passwords. 
    #null passwords = yes

    ## The old plaintext passdb backend. Some Samba features will not work if this passdb backend is used. (NOTE: enabled for size reasons)
    ## (tdbsam,smbpasswd,ldapsam)
    passdb backend = smbpasswd

    ## Set location of smbpasswd ('smbd -b' will show default compiled location)
    #smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd 

    ## LAN (IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY) WAN (IPTOS_THROUGHPUT) WiFi (SO_KEEPALIVE) try&error for buffer sizes (SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536)
    socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY

    ## If this integer parameter is set to a non-zero value, Samba will read from files asynchronously when the request size is bigger than this value.
    ## Note that it happens only for non-chained and non-chaining reads and when not using write cache.
    ## The only reasonable values for this parameter are 0 (no async I/O) and 1 (always do async I/O).
    ## (1/0)
    #aio read size = 0
    #aio write size = 0

    ## If Samba has been built with asynchronous I/O support, Samba will not wait until write requests are finished before returning the result to the client for files listed in this parameter.
    ## Instead, Samba will immediately return that the write request has been finished successfully, no matter if the operation will succeed or not.
    ## This might speed up clients without aio support, but is really dangerous, because data could be lost and files could be damaged. 
    #aio write behind = /*.tmp/

    ## lower CPU useage if supported and aio is disabled (aio read size = 0 ; aio write size = 0)
    ## is this still broken? issue is from 2019 (NOTE: see https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14095 )
    ## (no, yes)
    use sendfile = yes

    ## samba will behave as previous versions of Samba would and will fail the lock request immediately if the lock range cannot be obtained.
    #blocking locks = No

    ## disable loading of all printcap printers by default (iprint, cups, lpstat)
    load printers = No
    printcap name = /dev/null

    ## Enabling this parameter will disable Samba's support for the SPOOLSS set of MS-RPC's.
    disable spoolss = yes

    ## This parameters controls how printer status information is interpreted on your system.
    ## (BSD, AIX, LPRNG, PLP, SYSV, HPUX, QNX, SOFTQ)
    printing = bsd

    ## Disable that nmbd is acting as a WINS server for unknow netbios names
    #dns proxy = No

    ## win/unix user mapping backend
    #idmap config * : backend = tdb

    ## Allows the server name that is advertised through MDNS to be set to the hostname rather than the Samba NETBIOS name.
    ## This allows an administrator to make Samba registered MDNS records match the case of the hostname rather than being in all capitals.
    ## (netbios, mdns)
    mdns name = mdns

    ## Clients that only support netbios won't be able to see your samba server when netbios support is disabled.
    #disable netbios = Yes

    ## Setting this value to no will cause nmbd never to become a local master browser.
    #local master = no

    ## (auto, yes) If this is set to yes, on startup, nmbd will force an election, and it will have a slight advantage in winning the election. It is recommended that this parameter is used in conjunction with domain master = yes, so that nmbd can guarantee becoming a domain master. 
    #preferred master = yes

    ## (445 139) Specifies which ports the server should listen on for SMB traffic.
    ## 139 is netbios/nmbd
    #smb ports = 445 139

    ## This is a list of files and directories that are neither visible nor accessible.
    ## Each entry in the list must be separated by a '/', which allows spaces to be included in the entry. '*' and '?' can be used to specify multiple files or directories as in DOS wildcards.
    veto files = /Thumbs.db/.DS_Store/._.DS_Store/.apdisk/

    ## If a directory that is to be deleted contains nothing but veto files this deletion will fail unless you also set the delete veto files parameter to yes.
    delete veto files = yes
```

Folder share:

```
[HDDSoft]
        path = /media/HDDSoft/+PC
        create mask = 0666
        directory mask = 0777
        read only = yes
        guest ok = yes
        guest only = yes
```

Why Windows7 ask me password?

Comment: For context, this is a follow-on from [SAMBA(Openwrt) Share not show in File explorer (Windows 7)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/720354/100397)

Comment: Check you Windows Credentials (Wallet) in Control Panel to see what user account you're using to connect to the share. Look on the server in the log files to see what user account it thinks you're trying to log on with. Report both in your question please

Comment: @roaima Let's do like this. Since this question has nothing to do with the previous one, last time's post marks it as resolved. I decided to "split" the two questions.

Comment: @roaima In this case, the user of the win 7 computer is **foo** ... but I have no user **foo** on the samba server. Also, there is no entry in the win7 wallet

Comment: Check if both client and server are in the same workgroup.

Comment: Both have **WORKGROUP** as work group. When the login request appears (in windows 7) the message **Domain FOO-PC** also appears.

Comment: Does it ask password when you try to open server or share? Probably `security = share` in `[global]` may help. But you will not be able to configure per-user access to other shares.

Comment: I can see you split the questions - that's perfectly sensible. I was adding context, not intending criticism

Comment: sisi, I understood that @roaima, do not worry

Comment: @dimich the problem is that I have other shares set with the password ... if I remove this, as you rightly say, I can no longer login. But why does it ask me for the password on win 7 while not on windows 10? even if the ```security``` parameter is set to ```user```?

Comment: @vincenzogianfelice  Sorry, `security=share` is not valid anymore. According to smb.conf, with `security=user` : *With user-level security a client must first "log-on" with a valid username and password*. Try to play with `server role` in `[general]`. Also, for `map to guest = Bad User`: *Means user logins with an invalid password are rejected, unless the username does not exist*. Does Win7 user name match any user on server?

Comment: No, the user **foo** not exist on server

Comment: **UPDATE**: I also tried to set the password (user/password) and on **windows 7** it didn't work! It always says "**incorrect login**" when in reality the user/password pair is correct ... From all other PCs (linux/windows 10) i can access in quietly, but cant't on **windows 7** ... not even with a password! How is it possible?